# Drawing bitmaps as line on Canvas

Tags: android, kotlin, canvas

Now i am writing my small drawing app and one of it features will be custom brushes from bitmap. I thought that onTouchEvent() will call on every motion and drawing bitmap on every pixel won't be a big problem, but when i swipe fast the coordinates come slow and app [draw it with gaps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsFZD.jpg).
Anyone know how to draw line from point to point using Bitmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here
Create an ArrayList to hold the points/coordinates first

```
ArrayList<PointF> drawPoints=new ArrayList<>();
```

Then,create this method

```
public void draw1(float x,float y){
    PathMeasure pm=new PathMeasure(path1,false);
    float fSegmentLen=pm.getLength()/pm.getLength();
    Matrix m=new Matrix();
    int ox=-pattern.getWidth()/2;
    int oy=-pattern.getHeight()/2;

    for (int i=1;i<pm.getLength();i+=increment){
            pm.getMatrix(fSegmentLen*i,m,PathMeasure.POSITION_MATRIX_FLAG);
            m.preTranslate(ox,oy);
//change pattern below to the bitmap you want to draw
            drawCanvas.drawBitmap(pattern,m,drawPaint);
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Then Call the above method in onTouchEvent

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)  {
    float touchX=event.getX();
    float touchY=event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            firstPointX=touchX;
            firstPointY=touchY;
        case  MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                drawPoints.add(new PointF(touchX,touchY));
                if (drawPoints.size()>=2) {
                    PointF pointF = drawPoints.get(drawPoints.size()-2);
                    path1.moveTo(pointF.x, pointF.y);

                    PointF next = drawPoints.get(drawPoints.size() - 1);
                    path1.quadTo(pointF.x, pointF.y, next.x, next.y);
                    //path1.quadTo(firstPointX, firstPointY, next.x, next.y);
                    draw1(touchX,touchY);
                }
                invalidate();
                path1.reset();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            drawPoints.clear();
            path1.reset();
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

If you want it in Kotlin, you can just auto convert he code to kotlin in Android Studio
I hope that helps,let me know if it works